# How to activate window snapping in Gnome Shell?

Tags: gnome-shell

Gnome 3.X usually provides window snapping (tiling) and it is triggered by moving a window to the left or right edge of your screen. However, on my desktop this feature isn't working. Moving a window to the edge does not have any effect?
How could I activate window snapping in Gnome Shell without installing any extension?

Answer (score 5):

Mutter is the default window manager for GNOME 3, which led me to the gsetting to change for my installation:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter edge-tiling true
```

The desktop overrides, via `org.gnome.shell.overrides edge-tiling`, seemed to have no effect even after restarts. It would seem that the overrides should replace the mutter configs if I look at the override migration source code. Nevertheless, setting the mutter tiling solved it immediately (no restart required), and it worked with the overrides edge-tiling set to either `true` or `false`.

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, Gnome 3.28.2.

Answer (score 3):

It took my some hours to find out, how to activate this feature. However, if it does not work, try the following command in a terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.overrides edge-tiling true
```

To deactivate the feature again, use:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.overrides edge-tiling false
```